# Getting Error Code1175, while executing SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have written this query in my MYSQL 8.0.33 still it gives error 1175, below is the query

```
delete from employees
where managerid in (
    select managerid
    from managers
    where CATEGORY = "Sales"
)
and emp_id <> -1;
```

- `Managerid` - primary key of managers table
- `Emp_id` primary key of employees table

However this query works fine:-

```
delete from employees
where name in (
    select replace(managername, 'CC-', '') as name
    from managers
    where CATEGORY = "SALES"
)
and emp_id <> -1;
```

I
It should work. But giving error:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: This is not a MySQL Server error (for a start, it isn't a GUI application and it doesn't have menus). What's the title bar in the application window?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WorkBench as your client?
Anyway, the message clearly says what you need to do

Your solution would be something like:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
DELETE FROM employees WHERE managerid IN (SELECT managerid FROM managers WHERE CATEGORY = "Sales") AND emp_id <> -1;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Comment: "and emp_id <> -1 " works the same way I guess no need to change the SQL_SAFE_UPDATE everytime, so the solution is workaround not the exact solution